# Перевод string в double

Tags: c++, строки, double

Почему `stod("1.2")` выводит :

> 1.0000000000000000

?

Comment: @Gambit, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, дело в формате, с запятой определение проходит корректно.

Answer (score 2):

Русская локализация.

Добавьте в нужном месте

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");
```

и разделителем целой части в числе будет  точка (`.`), а не запятая (`,`).

Answer (score 0):

`atof()` пробовали?

Comment: откуда вы берете эту чертову "ы"?

Answer (score 0):

hashcode.ru/questions/211103/